# How do I reinstall Ubuntu distro to wsl?

Tags: server, permissions, data-recovery, windows-subsystem-for-linux, undelete

I accidentally deleted Ubuntu from  my computer, later I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and now I need to access my previous files.

When I installed 22.04 LTS I couldn’t find my previous account but I can't see the folder in explorer and  I don't have access to enter
[Alert windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2AWq.png)

translated would be some  cannot be accessed. you may not have permission to this network resource. Contact the admin of this server to check if you have access permissions
An attempt was made to access the invalid address

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I realize that you are not proficient in English, but your question is *extremely* unclear as it is written.  The best I can understand, you uninstalled Ubuntu from WSL, then installed 22.04 in WSL.  You are hoping to access files from the uninstalled version?  Do you have any backup from Windows?

Comment: yeah, that's correct, i haven't a backup from Windows

Comment: Ok, it's unlikely that you are going to be able to recover, but just-in-case, what's the folder that you are trying to access that is giving you an error?  Edit the question, if you would, to specify it.  Thanks.

Comment: the user wsl account  of uninstalled version